# Recover ADSI container for Exchange 2007

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange, active-directory

While using ADSI Edit I made a mistake deleting container **CN=Servers** from under `CN=Configuration , CN=Services, CN=Microsoft Exchange, CN=[YourExchangeOrganisationName], CN=Administrative Groups, CN=[LegacyAdministrativeGroupName], CN=Servers`

I deleted this folder while following [this link](http://www.techieshelp.com/cannot-email-mail-enabled-folders-after-exchange-2010-upgrade/)

This has caused Exchange services to stop running. Example:

> Service MSExchangeMailSubmission. Exchange topology discovery can't find the local Exchange server.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Do you have a backup of a domain controller, or the NTDS database?  Did you still have live servers in the legacy administrative group?

Comment: Yes we have an image of the entire server from 2 days ago. We can view the container within ADSI Edit on this system. Is there a way to export/import ADSI containers?

Comment: Is it possible to restore an ADSI container from active directory?

Comment: We ended up restoring the container from a backup via active directory authoritative restore. Case closed!

Comment: Great!  Sorry I didn't get back around to putting up an answer for you - but, put your solution up as an answer so that searchers can find it, we can upvote it, and you can mark it as accepted!